# Change virtual desktops orientation to vertical?

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I've installed newest Ubuntu and virtual desktops are laid out horizontally. How can I change them to vertical layout?

Comment: If you're looking for vertical workspaces, then you'll need to install [this GNOME Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4144/vertical-overview/). There is no option in the GUI (at this time) to allow a person to choose vertical over horizontal.

Answer (score 5):

Workspaces in Ubuntu 21.10 can be reverted to the vertical layout of previous versions by installing a dedicated Gnome Shell extension, [Vertical overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4144/vertical-overview/) by Ralthuis.

Comment: As much as I appreciate the work on that extension it is basically incorrect. Nothing is "reverted". It is essentially a hack and it is not as good as "native" vertical workspaces from the previous gnome version.

Comment: It's a shame it's not builtin given default shortcut (at least in 2021) will use down/up arrows or "page begin/page end" so a vertical-friendly workflow, which can quickly become very confusing.